# Footer added to itext pdf not visible in MS Edge and Firefox

Tags: pdf, firefox, itext, microsoft-edge

I am generating a pdf document using itext v5 and adding a footer containing current date and page numbers in a second pass at the end.
My code for adding the footer is like so :

```
public static void addFooter(ByteArrayOutputStream baos) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);       

    Font footerFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {

        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(++i));
        ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(20, 10, 575, 32));            
        ct.addText(new Chunk("--Date and copyright information--", footerFont));
        ct.go(); 
    }
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();         
}
```

The trouble is the footer is visible fine when the pdf is opened in Chrome, Adobe Reader and IE11 but not visible when opened using MS Edge (Which unfortunately is the default program for pdf in Windows 10) as well as Firefox Quantum 57

[image: screenshot]

What could I be doing wrong? Is their a work-around for MS Edge to fix such weird rendering issues?

**Edit:**

Adding pdf validation output from https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx:

[image]

Seems like itext IS doing something wrong with the xref tables, but not sure what or how to fix it

Comment: As far as I can see, you're not doing anything wrong. MS Edge and the PDF viewer in Firefox are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
The correct way was to create a new ByteArrayOutputStream and initialize the PdfStamper with that BAOS and then return it. I changed the code to the following and now there are no xref validation errors and all clients display the footer correctly.

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream addFooter(ByteArrayOutputStream baos) throws IOException, DocumentException {
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, out );       

Font footerFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);

for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {

    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(++i));
    ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(20, 10, 575, 32));            
    ct.addText(new Chunk("--Date and copyright information--", footerFont));
    ct.go(); 
}
stamper.close();
reader.close();    
return out; }
```